# Laravel 8, trying to check if user has been verified during login returns an error

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 8 in combination with vue and I am trying show an message when a user that tries to login before this user has verified his/her emailaddress.

```
    // loginController.php
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        if (Auth::client()->verified != 1) {
            //good
        }else{
            // bad, message users needs to verify email first
        }
    }else{
          //login not correct try again
    }
```

Now I am getting this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/home' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/api/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: check whether verified or not before login attempt. and what error you are exactly getting??

Comment: well auth client will cause an error not sure which yet

Comment: Auth::user()->verified

Comment: You should be handlng CORS request. install this pakage, https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors.

Comment: Yeah I know but this package did not solve the issue, still gettings this error

Comment: are you validating data??

Comment: yes the basic required fields validation which works

Comment: i don't think so..can you share your full code?? why is your api call is getting redirected to the web??

Comment: I will try to see if I can post more code, and Im not sure why its redirecting(this line was removed)